# Using WINAPI in Qt applications

Tags: winapi, qt4, integration

Can anybody tell if I can use the Windows APIs in my qt application?
If yes can anybody tell me the procedure to do it? I need to use the msdn winapi "GetSystemPowerStatus" in my qt application to show the battery status in my qt GUI based application.

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0/qsystemdeviceinfo.html#batteryLevel-prop ???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use those APIs (generally speaking), by including the appropriate header files.

It will make your code platform-specific (non-portable), so if there is a cross-platform way of doing so, I would use that.